# Jenkins freestyle abort command or steps

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Does anyone know a command or steps to abort a Jenkins Freestyle job?

I can use a timeout after 3 minutes but I don't see anyway to instantly exit like Pipeline jobs can by setting `currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED`'.

I'm running Jenkins on Windows so looking for a bat command or similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can add "kill" to the end of the path of any running job's execution,

Ex: `https://hostname/jenkins/job/DDNS/4902/kill`

and it will take you to a page that says:

```
This URL requires POST

The URL you're trying to access requires that requests be sent using POST (like a form submission). The button below allows you to retry accessing this URL using POST. URL being accessed:

https://hostname/jenkins/job/DDNS/4902/kill

If you were sent here from an untrusted source, please proceed with caution.
```

There will be a button for "Retry Using POST" -- click that and it will automatically kill any running job, aborting at current stage.

Therefore, if you want to make a script, use that URL with some logic to land on the right job number, with a POST method, and it should do what you want.